# Java regex to get part number

Tags: java, regex

I have HTML that I need to extract a part number from, the HTML looks like:

```
javascript:selectItem('ABC123          1', '.....
```

I need to get the ABC123 from the above.

My code snippet:

```
Patterp p = Pattern.Compile("?????");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);

if(m.find())
  partNumber = m.group(1).trim();
```

BTW, in the pattern, how do I escape for the character `(`

I now for quotes I do `\"`

thanks allot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escape `(` by putting a `\` before it. Because it's in a `String`, you need to escape the `\` so the sequence is `\\(`. This should parse that snippet:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("javascript:selectItem\\('(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
if (m.find()) {
  String partNumber = m.group(1);
}
```

I've assumed the part number is one or more word characters (meaning digits, letters or underscore).

Comment: How would I match any character but the < character?

Comment: So then I would do ([^<]) to make it a capture group?

Comment: @Blankman that would capture one character. You want `([^<]*)` to capture zero or more characters that aren't `<`. Since you expect at least one I would do `([^<]+)` to capture one or more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=selectItem\\(')\\S*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
}
```